# jquery "in" selector when affect css inside an iframe

Tags: jquery, css, node-webkit

I'm trying to manipulate font size inside of an iframe by using keycodes in a node webkit container.

I've got some code that works on a td element in the iframe, but when I try to remove the td part of the selector, I get this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'fontSize' in undefined`

Here is my "working" code.

```
    var iframe = top.frames['contentIframe'].document;
    var curSize = parseInt($('td', iframe).css('font-size'));
    if (e.ctrlKey === true && e.keyCode === 107) {
        curSize += 1;
        $('td', iframe).css('font-size', curSize+'px');
    };

    if (e.ctrlKey === true && e.keyCode === 109) {
        curSize -= 1;
        $('td', iframe).css('font-size', curSize+'px');
    };
```

Here is the non-working code:

```
var iframe = top.frames['contentIframe'].document;
var curSize = parseInt($(iframe).css('font-size'));
if (e.ctrlKey === true && e.keyCode === 107) {
    curSize += 1;
    $(iframe).css('font-size', curSize+'px');
};

if (e.ctrlKey === true && e.keyCode === 109) {
    curSize -= 1;
    $(iframe).css('font-size', curSize+'px');
};
```

But I need to be able to affect more than just elements inside a td. How would I be able to make it so I can affect the font-size in the whole iframe?

Comment: Show the non-working code, not the working code. How can we tell what you're doing wrong?

Comment: As I said, the non-working code is the equivalent minus the ```td``` in the selector. I'll edit my post anyway.

Comment: How about `$('body', iframe)`?

Comment: I've tried it, does not work.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. You need to specify some element in the iframe whose CSS you're trying to read and update.

Comment: Remember, `.css()` only works for elements that have an explicit `style="font-size: xx"`` attribute, it doesn't get the computed style.

Comment: I wasn't aware that .css only works for elements that have a font size to them... that's the reason why it's not working on all of the pages, because not all of them have font sizes. I'm not sure what I should do from here... it'll take some thinking.

Comment: Search for `getComputedStyle`